# I want to draw an up arrow on the right side of an array with a text on both the sides of arrow

Tags: latex

I have written the following Latex code to get an array as an output:

The code:

```
\begin{center}
    \[      
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
        \textbf{Base} & \textbf{Quotient} & \textbf{Remainder}\\
        \hline
        2 & 23 & 1\\
        \hline
        2 & 11 & 1\\
        \hline
        2 & 5 & 1\\
        \hline
        2 & 2 & 0\\
        \hline
        2 & 1 & 1\\
        \hline
          & 0 &  \\
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{center}
```

The output obtained is shown in the below image:

[image: Obtained output]

I want to add an up arrow on the right side of this table with LSB at top of arrow and MSB at bottom of arrow which is shown in the following image.

[image: Desired Output]

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: `tikzmark` package can probably help. Can you make a [mre] ?